# What is the significance of 'this == null'?

Tags: java

What does this ever mean in the block.

```
if (this == null) {
    // some code
}
else {
    // ...
}
```

My concern is will `this == null` ever be true? The Java compiler does not show any error.

Comment: As far as I can think, `this` can never be `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this == null` will never be true. The Java compiler will indeed let you do a few things such as that that have no real purpose, such as `if (1==2) {}` or `throw null;`

Answer (score 0):

`this == null` always evaluates to `false` in Java